# can't install google chrome

Tags: 17.04, deb

I went on the chrome page and chose the ubuntu linux system it downloads the package .deb I open it and the "install" button does not accent anything and does not install

my version of ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Before using Ubuntu Software for whichever reason, you should fully update your system. Can be done easily by opening Updates and installing what's being offered.

Answer (score 1):

You're downloading a .deb file, which probably isn't going to open automatically or self-install.

Open up the Terminal (look for it in Applications), navigate to where you downloaded the file (most likely, ~/Downloads) and enter:

```
sudo dpkg -i google*.deb
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Sometimes it will give an error, saying you're missing a library. You can enter:

```
sudo apt fix-broken install
```

Then look in Applications, Chrome should be there.

Comment: It's often easier to just do `sudo apt install ./google*.deb`, which will pull in and pre-install dependencies as well.

Comment: And Chromium != (Google) Chrome. The former is available in the Ubuntu repositories, the latter isn't and must be installed with the provided .deb (or by manually adding Google's repository).

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and follow the steps

1. go to downloads directory `cd downloads`
2. when enter this command `ls`
3. copy and paste your .deb package and enter `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/YourPackage.deb`
4. replace the "YourPackage.deb" and paste your .deb package and find your application in ubuntu